# root.after is not recursing to the same function - Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading, tk-toolkit

I'm having a problem with the root.after function in Tkinter.

I'm trying to run a subprocess, and while it runs, I check for the process.poll(), if it's still None, then call back the checking function:

```
self.PingProcess = subprocess.Popen(
    r'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "file1.ps1"',
    stdout=sys.stdout)
self.PingContinuous() # Checks the PingProcess poll until the process is finished

AceThread = threading.Thread(target=self.CheckAce())
AceThread.start()
DrivesThread = threading.Thread(target=self.CheckDrives())
DrivesThread.start()
self.continuous_check() # Checks the AceThread and DrivesThread (there are
                        # processes in them)

def PingContinuous(self):
    PingProcess = self.PingProcess.poll()
    if PingProcess is None:
        self.ui.root.after(500, self.PingContinuous)
    else:
        print("Finished")

def CheckAce(self):
    self.AceProcess = subprocess.Popen(
        r'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "file.ps1"',
        stdout=sys.stdout)

def CheckDrives(self):
    self.DrivesProcess = subprocess.Popen(
        r'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "file3.ps1"',
        stdout=sys.stdout)

def continuous_check(self):
    AceProcess = self.AceProcess.poll()
    DrivesProcess = self.DrivesProcess.poll()
    if PingProcess is None and DrivesProcess is None:
        self.ui.root.after(500, self.continuous_check)
    else:
        print("Finished Ace and Drives")
```

The problem is that the `PingContinuous()` should keep running recursively with the

```
self.ui.root.after(500, self.PingContinuous)
```

But instead, it just jumps back to the:

```
AceThread = threading.Thread(target=self.CheckAce())
AceThread.start()
DrivesThread = threading.Thread(target=self.CheckDrives())
DrivesThread.start()
self.continuous_check() # Checks the AceThread and DrivesThread (there are
                        # processes in them)
```

and it starts to jump back and forth between `self.continuous_check` and `self.PingContinuous`.

What I need is for the `PingProcess` to finish, and then run the rest of the threads.

**I can't use time.sleep or process.wait(), because this will freeze my GUI**

Comment: Your `root.after()` code looks good, although you haven't shown enough of your program to be sure.  However, you didn't do the threads right - `target=self.CheckAce()` (for example) is a single, *immediate* call of the function; its return value (None) becomes the target of the Thread.

Comment: @jasonharper so what do you think I should do?

Comment: Start with getting rid of the `()` in both of the Thread creations - and add at least the definition of `continuous_check()` to your posted code, as that looks relevant.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried getting rid of them, but the problem is that it doesn't enter the thread, it just continues to the next line.
I'll edit the post for the continious_check()

Comment: Of course it continues to the next line - that's the whole point of a thread!

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, but I need it to keep stucking in the 'PingContinuous(self)' until the ping process is finished!

Comment: BTW, having `PingContinuous()` call `after()` to reschedule to have itself run again later is not recursion — it's simply serial processing (so maybe you could all it iteration). Regardless, you're going to need to provide more code to get any real help. Many of the functions are methods of some class definition you've left out.

Answer (score 0):

`PingContinuous` isn't blocking. You're calling it (which is presumably working), it sets up a call to itself in a new thread for later on, then carries on into the `AceThread` stuff.

You could run `PingContinuous` in a new thread in a loop rather than recursively, and then have your main thread `join` the new thread before carrying on (so that it'll block until PingContinuous finishes)? Something like this:

```py
def PingContinuous(self):
  while not self.PingProcess.poll():
    # You might want a maximum number of iterations before giving up, too
    # so that you don't loop forever if it's broken
    time.sleep(500)
  print("Finished")

pingThread = threading.Thread(target=self.PingContinuous)
pingThread.start()
pingThread.join()

# Now carry on with AceThread etc. here
```

...but this may block your GUI as well, depending on how you're running that. You probably need your GUI and your program logic to be in separate threads so that you can block one without blocking the other.

Comment: You made the same mistake the OP did in their threading - `target=self.PingContinuous()` calls the function *right now*, and executes nothing in the thread because the function returns None.

Comment: Yes, yes I did. And I make that same mistake every time I call threading.Thread, anywhere. I really should have learned by now. Thank you!

Comment: Actually time.sleep() does freeze my GUI, the question is why root.after doesn't work properly?

Comment: time.sleep() freezes your GUI because your GUI is in the same thread as the rest of your logic (presumably). The GUI needs to be in the main thread, so you need to spin a separate thread up for everything else. Then you can block that thread without blocking your GUI.

Comment: @BenTaylor I'm not sure how to do that actually :(

Comment: @George: If you use `after()` properly you shouldn't need to create a separate thread. Having `PingContinuous()` call it is a way of polling the status without needing to call `sleep()` and interfere with the GUI's `mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `.after()` in your code works fine.

Actually you don't need to run `self.CheckAce()` and `self.CheckDrives()` using threads:

```py
...
self.CheckAce()
self.CheckDrives()
self.continuous_check()
...
```

Also there is typo inside `continuous_check()`: `PingProcess` should be `AceProcess`.

```py
def continuous_check(self):
    AceProcess = self.AceProcess.poll()
    DrivesProcess = self.DrivesProcess.poll()
    # Typo: PingProcess should be AceProcess instead
    if AceProcess is None and DrivesProcess is None:
        self.ui.root.after(500, self.continuous_check)
    else:
        print("Finished Ace and Drives")
```